# Is there an analogue of OpenGL's ImageLoadStore in DirectX 12?

Tags: shader, directx12, image-load-store

I'm trying to port part of an OpenGL program into an existing DirectX 12 software, at some point in their shaders they use OpenGL [ImageLoadStore](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) in order to store information in 3D Textures without having to use an FBO.

Is there something similar in the DirectX 12 API? 
Or would I have to render to a custom FrameBuffer?

Comment: [This related question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/4422/6) and its answers should get you a little further. DirectX 12 is actually more similar to Vulkan than to OpenGL, but with the help of those tables you should be able to figure out the further DirectX keywords you should be looking for. But...rest assured that something to the effect of loading/storing data in aribtrary memory locations of arbitrary textures is definitely possible in DirectX 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [RWTexture3D](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwtexture3d).
The [hlsl documentation page about RWTexture2D](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwtexture2d) also has sample code that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing atm. Your second link is pointing to RWTexture3D, I tihnk you meant [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwtexture2d)